# failed to add item into an array in the foreach loop

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework and i am having a problem while i was trying to add items into an array.

first i created a db table object:

```
$questionTable = new xxx();
        $db = $questionTable->getAdapter();
        $sql = "select * from questions where value='v'";
        $res = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

the $res is an array which looks like this in JSON [{'a':1},{'a':2},{'a':3}]

then i used a foreach :

```
foreach($res as $element)
        {
            $value = $element['a'];

            if($value == 2)
            {

                $element['extra'] = 10;



            }
        }
```

then when i print out the result using:

```
echo Zend_Json_Encoder::encode($res);
```

it remains [{'a':1},{'a':2},{'a':3}].

does anyone know how to fix it?

thx in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a magical ampersand to your `$element`

```
foreach($res as &$element)
----------------^
```